# how to convert utf-8 to simple html node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, utf-8

I am reading an HTML file with filereader in node.js

```
fs.readFile('public/template.html', { encoding: 'utf-8' }, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.render('website', { body: data });
});
```

It renders `utf-8` encoded string , But I want to be able to use the content as DOM in front end. Is there any way of changing encoding or a way to convert it into simple HTML?

It shows me after sending header as- `text/html`

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting the content type header? [Here](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.set)'s a reference

Comment: @nightgaunt, It is still encoded to utf8

Comment: Can you please add your website view?

Comment: what are the content of website.jade?

Comment: Yup.. Need to see the website.ejs / website.jade code.